# Maximum variance partitioning graph into disjoints cliques

Tags: graph-theory, clustering

I am working on the following problem: Let $G = \left(V, E\right)$ an undirected graph such that every vertex $i\in V$, has a label $x_i \in \mathbb R$. For every vertex subset $S \subset V$, we define $$\text{Var}(S) = \frac1{|S|} \sum_{i \in S} \left(x_i - \frac1{|S|} \sum_{j\in S} x_j\right)^2$$ the variance of $S$. The question asks for partitioning $G$ into disjoint cliques $\left(C_k\right)_{k}$ in order to maximize the total variance $$\sum_{k}\text{Var}\left(C_k\right).$$ I think that K-means can be used here but I do not know how? Can anyone helps me to find an idea for solving this problem?

Comment: wait what is "the question"? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: The question is to find an algorithm or a heuristic to have the best partition.

Comment: that is computer science, not math. "algorithm" is very annoying to define rigorously

Comment: Do the labels have anything to do with the graph structure? Your definition of variance doesn't seem to use the fact that there are *edges* at all.

Comment: For data in R^n, PCA is equivalent to a maximum variance problem, but there you're maximizing the variance in terms of Euclidean distance, not arbitrary labels.

Comment: Oh, I see, you also require that every cluster is a clique, i.e. is a complete subgraph? In that case you're unlikely to have an efficient algorithm to do this - even checking whether graph has a k-clique of size k is NP complete. So if your plan is to do optimization on the space of all cliques, you might be able to do only slightly better than brute force.

Comment: For some clarification, is it necessary that the graph partitions into k cliques of size k? Or were those intended to be two different variables? If they're the same, then most graphs won't even have a partition, period.